# Spring Managed Consumer Interceptors

Tags: spring-kafka

Following https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2049,
wouldn't it make sense to also support consumer interceptors?

The consumer interceptor may be set on the *ConsumerProperties* before being used by the *ListenerConsumer*. To simplify the usage, a composite and an empty interceptor could also be provided.

A similar approach could also be used for Kafka streams.

I can contribute on this request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense; but we might want to make the existing `RecordInterceptor` and `BatchInterceptor` extend `ConsumerInterceptor` instead of adding more properties, to avoid any confusion.

Looking forward to the contribution.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply. Except for the onCommit method, listeners are already supporting interceptor through the record and batch interceptors. Updating these interceptors to extend ConsumerInterceptor would be weird as both kind of interceptors are defining methods to intercept but with different names and parameters. So, it may complexify and introduce confusion. Maybe I missed something. Github issue proposing another approach has been created to continue the discussion https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2244.